# in RecyclerView i want onclicklistner operation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Code is for recyclerview I want to implement click operation in child option separately.
how should i implement the given code below this code?

this my project code with adapter,child,parent

**adapter.java**

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Adapter.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter;
import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Model.ParentObject;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models.TitleChild;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models.TitleParent;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.R;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.ViewHolder.TitleChildViewHolder;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.ViewHolder.TitleParentViewHolder;

import java.util.List;



public class adapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<TitleParentViewHolder,TitleChildViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public adapter(Context context, List<ParentObject> parentItemList) {
        super(context, parentItemList);
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public TitleParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent,viewGroup,false);
    return new TitleParentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public TitleChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child,viewGroup,false);
        return new TitleChildViewHolder(view);    }

    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(TitleParentViewHolder titleParentViewHolder, int i, Object o) {
        TitleParent title =(TitleParent)o;
        titleParentViewHolder._textview.setText(title.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(TitleChildViewHolder titleChildViewHolder, int i, Object o) {
        TitleChild title =(TitleChild)o;
        titleChildViewHolder.op1.setText(title.getop1());
        titleChildViewHolder.op2.setText(title.getop2());
        titleChildViewHolder.op3.setText(title.getop3());
        titleChildViewHolder.op4.setText(title.getop4());
        titleChildViewHolder.op5.setText(title.getop5());


    }
}
```

**TitleChild.java**

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models;



public class TitleChild {
    public String op1;
    public String op2;
    public String op3;
    public String op4;
    public String op5;


    public TitleChild(String op1, String op2, String op3, String op4,String op5) {
        this.op1 = op1;
        this.op2 = op2;
        this.op3 = op3;
        this.op4 = op4;
        this.op5 = op5;

    }

    public String getop1() {return op1;}

    public void setop1(String op1) {this.op1 = op1;}

    public String getop2() {return op2;}

    public void setop2(String op2) {this.op2 = op2;}

    public String getop3() {return op3;}

    public void setop3(String op3) {this.op3 = op3;}

    public String getop4() {return op4;}

    public void setop4(String op4) {this.op4 = op4;}
    public String getop5() {return op5;}

    public void setop5(String op5) {this.op5 = op5;}
}
```

**TitleCreator.java**

```
 package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models;

    import android.content.Context;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;



    public class TitleCreator {
        static TitleCreator _titleCreator;
        List<TitleParent> _titleParents;

        public TitleCreator(Context context) {
            _titleParents = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=1;i<=8;i++)
            {
                TitleParent title = new TitleParent(String.format("SEM%d",i));
                _titleParents.add(title);
            }

        }


        public static TitleCreator get(Context context)
        {
            if (_titleCreator==null)
                _titleCreator=new TitleCreator(context);
                return _titleCreator;
        }

        public List<TitleParent> getall() {
            return _titleParents;
        }
    }

**TitleParent.java** 

package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models;

import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Model.ParentObject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TitleParent implements ParentObject {

    private List<Object> mChildrenList;
    private UUID _id;
    private String title;

    public TitleParent(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        _id=UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public UUID get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(UUID _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> getChildObjectList() {
        return mChildrenList;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChildObjectList(List<Object> list) {
     mChildrenList=list;
    }
}
```

**TitleChildViewHolder.java**

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.ViewHolder;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ViewHolder.ChildViewHolder;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.R;


public class TitleChildViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    public TextView op1,op2,op3,op4,op5;

    public TitleChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        op1 =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.op1);
        op2 =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.op2);
        op3 =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.op3);
        op4 =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.op4);
        op5 =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.op5);

    }
}
```

**TitleParentViewHolder.java**

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution.ViewHolder;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.ViewHolder.ParentViewHolder;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.R;



public class TitleParentViewHolder extends ParentViewHolder {
    public TextView _textview;
    public ImageButton _imagebutton;
    public TitleParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        _textview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
        _imagebutton =(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandArrow);


    }
}
```

**SYFragment.java**

```
package com.blipclap.engineering_solution;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Model.ParentObject;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Adapter.adapter;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models.TitleChild;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models.TitleCreator;
import com.blipclap.engineering_solution.Models.TitleParent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SYFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        ((adapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    private List<ParentObject> initData() {
        TitleCreator titleCreator =TitleCreator.get(getActivity());
        List<TitleParent> titles = titleCreator.getall();
        List<ParentObject> parentObjects =new ArrayList<>();
        for (TitleParent title:titles)
        {
            List<Object> childList =new ArrayList<>();
            childList.add(new TitleChild("I.T","C.E","EXTC","MECH","CIVIL" ));
            title.setChildObjectList(childList);
            parentObjects.add(title);
        }
        return parentObjects;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sy, container, false);
        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        adapter adapter =new adapter(getActivity(),initData());
        adapter.setParentClickableViewAnimationDefaultDuration();
        adapter.setParentAndIconExpandOnClick(true);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Syllabus");
    }
}
```

**list_child.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/op1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="op1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/op2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/op1"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="op2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/op3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/op2"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="op3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/op4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/op3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="op4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/op5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/op4"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="op5" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

**list_parent.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parentTitle"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/expandArrow"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**fragment_sy.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blipclap.engineering_solution.SYFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**click code**

How should i implement this code in my project it should be like whenever i click clid option specific pdf should open

Anyone can help with this.

whenever i add this i end up with errors.

```
@Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(IssueViewHolder issueViewHolder, int position, Object childListItem) {
        Issue issue = (Issue) childListItem;
        issueViewHolder.bind(issue);

      issueViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //your code
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define interface in your adapter class

```
public interface onItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
    }

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener listener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = listener;
    }
```

On your Custom View Holder Implement `View.OnClickListner` and set Click Listener for required view.

```
public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

CustomViewHolder(View itemView){
super(itemView);
yourview.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
}
```

Now in the Adapter object just add setOnItemClickListener and you can bifurcate click event using the id of the view.

```
yourAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new YourAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
    // view.getId()
});
```

Comment: Will each option open separately has clicked ??

Comment: Set setOnClickListener on each view that you want click event.. So that you can get on onItemClickListner with respective id and position